# Azure webapp deployment fails after removing Composer SiteExtension

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I had Composer Site extension installed till now on azure php webapp. 
I need custom deployment that can run grunt tasks also. So I created the .deployment and deploy.sh files in project root. But that deploy.sh is not being picked up.

.deployment file contents:

```
[config]
command = bash deploy.sh
```

Looking at the deployment logs, I find this

```
2017-05-04T06:21:03.9301086Z,Updating submodules.,8bc3029f-d77b-4c1e-860f-a3d439d7a354,0
2017-05-04T06:21:03.9926050Z,Preparing deployment for commit id 'e2b45fb52b'.,61c286b1-5c00-4c11-ae14-54e0711d6857,0
2017-05-04T06:21:04.2632947Z,Running custom deployment command...,e71c397e-bc63-4357-abc4-acd49bc2041d,0
2017-05-04T06:21:04.3101663Z,Running deployment command...,24db1c4f-8a51-463b-8c4a-ee040bc5dfd8,0
    2017-05-04T06:21:04.3101663Z,Command: D:\home\SiteExtensions\ComposerExtension\Hooks\deploy.cmd,,0
    2017-05-04T06:21:04.4039215Z,The system cannot find the path specified.,,1
    2017-05-04T06:21:04.4195462Z,The system cannot find the path specified.\r\nD:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Kudu\62.60430.2807\bin\Scripts\starter.cmd D:\home\SiteExtensions\ComposerExtension\Hooks\deploy.cmd,,2
```

Seems like somewhere the trigger for Composer site extension still remains which is being invoked during deployment.

How can I completely remove Composer site extension and use my custom deployment script deploy.sh? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem. After uninstalling Composer SiteExtension, this environment variable is still present `APPSETTING_COMMAND = D:\home\SiteExtensions\ComposerExtension\Hooks\deploy.cmd`. Deleted the environment variable using kudu console and then deployment succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

After removing the Composer Extension the APPSETTING_COMMAND remains as an environment variable.

Use the Kudu PowerShell command `Remove-Item Env:\APPSETTING_COMMAND` to remove the variable online.

Alternatively, restarting the App Service via the overview tab will refresh the environment variables, though this could be a little invasive.